# How to set dynamic #id(*ngFor) and obtain the value from it in Angular2?

Tags: html, angular, data-binding

I have in my HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let package of packages">
  <td *ngFor="let coverage of coverages">
    <input type="hidden" #dynamicID [value]="coverage.id">
    <-- Here is one input, maybe put the identifier with the variable package -->
    <input #dynamicValue type="text" name="">
    <-- Another input, maybe put the identifier with the variable package -->
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" (click)="setPackage(package.id, dynamicID.value, dynamicValue.value)">Guardar</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I need to obtain values from inputs in my function setPackage.
If I put the same #id in the inputs, doesn't work. Always give me a error of can't obtain value from undefined.

Comment: This doesn't answer you question, but is the coverages always exactly the same in each package, since packages and coverages aren't connected in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use 2 way binding for your inputs? If so, you need to use something like `<input [(ngModel)]="coverage.id">`. You can take a look at this documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html